# Use Textarea for CSVWidget with django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I use `django-filter` to provide search form for a large dataset. It is for scientists who'd like to provide the sample IDs and get a filtered list.

For that purpose I'd like to have `<textarea>` instead of `<input type="text">` as they would just paste a dozen or more IDs at once and it would be good if they have overview of the submitted values.

Here is my code:

```
from django import forms
import django_filters as filters

class TextareaCSVWidget(filters.widgets.BaseCSVWidget, forms.Textarea):
    """
    The widget should create textarea.
    """
    pass

class CharInFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.CharFilter):
    """
    The filter should accept coma separated strings.
    """
    pass

class SampleFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    sample_ids = CharInFilter(
        name='sample_id',
        widget=TextareaCSVWidget()
    )
```

Now the textarea is properly displayed. The search works as expected.

However there is one weird issue: when I enter more than one value (separated by coma), after submitting the search form the textarea is replaced by `<input type="text">` (the entered values are preserved). This looks very awkward and I need to prevent this behaviour.

This doesn't happen if I enter a single value in the textarea.

What's wrong with my approach?

EDIT:

After posting the question I threw a better look in the source code of `django-filter` and here is the relevant part of the class `BaseCSVWidget` which I use to create the `TextareaCSVWidget`:

```
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    if not self._isiterable(value):
        value = [value]

    if len(value) <= 1:
        # delegate to main widget (Select, etc...) if not multiple values
        value = value[0] if value else ''
        return super(BaseCSVWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)

    # if we have multiple values, we need to force render as a text input
    # (otherwise, the additional values are lost)
    surrogate = forms.TextInput()
    value = [force_text(format_value(surrogate, v)) for v in value]
    value = ','.join(list(value))

    return surrogate.render(name, value, attrs)
```

The emphasised part is decisive. What should I do now? Overriding the `render` method doesn't look promissing to me. I don't want to lose the entered values.

I could manipulate this with JavaScript and replace the input element with textarea on document load, if nothing else helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overriden the `render` method and it works fine. Here is my solution:

```
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    if not self._isiterable(value):
        value = [value]

    if len(value) <= 1:
        # delegate to main widget (Select, etc...) if not multiple values
        value = value[0] if value else ''
        return super(TextareaCSVWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)

     value = ','.join(value)
     return super(TextareaCSVWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)
```

The emphasised part is the change. This renders the `textarea` properly and preserves the user input. I suppose the authors haven't taken into account the HTML element `textarea` when creating this widget and therefore forcing an `input` element of *type* `text`. It wouldn't be possible to place multiple coma separated values for example in `<input type="number">`.

If someone has a better solution I'd be still happy to get a better answer.